# Total dynamic head calculation of a submersible pump with different dia pipes connected to its discharge

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, pumps

[image]I have to install a submersible pump for pumping ground water to irrigate land. I have six inch diameter metal pipe already available that I plan to use in the project. The pump delivery is 5 inches and the delivery at top is also 5 inches, my question is, will the larger dia pipe in the middle effect the head calculation for this water pumping system or not.

Comment: Cant you determine the pressure loss due to the pipework using the Darcy-Weisbach equation?

Comment: I am not familiar with the Darcy weisbach equation. The water that the pump has to lift is almost 80 feet but I think that as I have increased the delivery pipe diameter by almost 50 percent, there will be more force of water on the pump and the pump head will also increase to 120 feet. Pipe replacement will be costly for me but if larger dia pipe decreases the total volume of water that I will get, I will have to replace the pipe.

Comment: Can you please explain how you increased the delivery pipe diameter by 50%?

Comment: Sorry, the cross sectional area was increased by almost 50 percent.

Comment: Can I ask what the model of the pump is?

Comment: Komax FX8-110, two stages of this pump to be used with an 11 KW motor. https://www.komaxmotor.com/fx/2-submersible-pump/8-komax-submersible-pump-fx8-and-fx10

Comment: It seems like having a bigger pipe should help the situtation, please have a look at this calculator available online. https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/darcy-weisbach

Comment: Do you know what material the pipes are from?

Comment: Pipes are of steel, and I cannot use bigger pump as the borehole is of 10 inches and the bigger pump is more the 8 inches in external dia. There is a risk of pump getting stuck if we ever need to pull it out for maintenance.

Comment: you do not understand the question well enough to ask what needs to be asked.  Head Loss plus height are the two components of pressure you must overcome to get to the outlet.  Head loss is greater in smaller pipes due to the ratio of circumference to area.  You need to go understand how head loss is calculated, explaining that is beyond the scope of this stack.  A larger pipe giving greater resistance to flow due to weight of water is a gross conceptual error.

Comment: Thanks, your assesment that I don't have much understanding of the concept is correct. I do not have much understanding of how pumps work. Can you please tell that will the use of a larger diameter pipe result in less or more then rated volume of water at the discharge.

Comment: Larger diameter in the middle will affect.  You can think of resistance as approximately proportional to length and inversely proportional to area.  (Non-gravitational) head loss can then be thought of as approximately proportional to this resistance and to flow rate.  It may be oversimplifying because it ignores a lot, but you should keep it as simple as you can.